# Remove percentage sign from values in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a lot of rows with values with percentage sign that I would like to remove from a column.

Is there a good SQL query to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourColumn = REPLACE(YourColumn, '%', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update your_table set your_column = replace(your_column, '%', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS does NOT have a "replace" function, you will have to use character substitution using several string functions.

Here is an example in Sybase and SQL Server.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = stuff(YourColumn, patindex(YourColumn, '%'), 1, NULL)
```

This code will find the pattern of '%' in YourColumn, then use that position number to replace the character with NULL.